# Can't Execute Stored Procedure with sqlsrv in php

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I have this Stored Procedure in my Database:

```
Parameter         Data Type   Output Parameter
@PIdPuesto        int         No
@PFechaProgramada datetime    No
@PEmail           varchar(50) No
@PXml             varchar(max)No
@PIdSobre         char(6)     Yes
@PStatus          int         Yes
@PStatusDescripcionvarchar(100) yes
```

And actually I'm trying to execute it with this lines of code:

```
    $fecha = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $fecha);
    $fecha = $fecha->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $xml = $this->_encodingUtf8Latin1($xml);

$idSobre;
$status;
$statusDescripcion;

$params = array(
  array(&$puente, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
  array(&$fecha, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
  array(&$email, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
  array(&$xml, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
  array(&$idSobre, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
  array(&$status, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT),
  array(&$statusDescripcion, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT)
);

$query = "EXEC USP_GrabaSobreTest @PIdPuesto = ?, @PFechaProgramada = ?, @PEmail = ?, @PXml = ?, @PIdSobre = ?, @PStatus = ?, @PStatusDescripcion = ?";

$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($this->$_base, $query, $params);

if($stmt === false)
{
  echo "Error in executing statement 3.\n";
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
else
{
 $resultado = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
}
```

But this does nothing, I have a function that show me the values of input and output variables and this is the result:

```
string(1) "2"
string(19) "2021-09-03 03:40:00"
string(14) "JUAN@GMAIL.COM"
string(768) "<MANIFIESTO><HEADER ID_SOBRE=""
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

The 3 last NULL variables are because the Stored Procedure are not working, maybe I have a problem with my syntax in the query?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Also, as is mention in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-retrieve-output-parameters-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-ver15), when _...retrieving an output or input/output parameter, all results returned by the stored procedure must be consumed before the returned parameter value is accessible_.